# Django: hashlib keeps generating same hex digest

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True, null=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    # .. and other fields

    def save(self):
        if self.hash is None:
            string_seed = str(self.created_at).encode('utf-8') + str(self.pk).encode('utf-8')
            self.hash = hashlib.sha224(string_seed).hexdigest()
        super(Book, self).save()
```

But I keep getting this error `"Duplicate entry 'c19c...abb5' for key 'store_book_hash_4517c5ea_uniq'"` after inputting second data (book, in this case). I don't know why my code keeps generating same value.

I use django admin page for data entry, and I thought when inserting new book via "Add book" form in django admin, the `self.hash` should always be `None`, so new random value would be freshly generated (but in my case, it wouldn't and threw integrity error instead). I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I really did not notice that `string_seed` will always contain `'NoneNone'`, so the value will always be the same. My chosen workaround is using `datetime`:

```
string_seed = str(datetime.datetime.now()).encode('utf-8')
```

or calling the `super().save()` first.